# SQL, Self join on 3 joined tables

Tags: sql, join

**Tables and requested output**
[image]

I'm using National Instrumets Teststand default database setup. I've tried to simplify the DB layout in the picture above.

I can manage to get what i want through some rather "complicated" sql, and it's very slow.

I think there is a better way, and then i stumbled over SELF JOIN. Basically what I want is to get data values from several different rows, from one "serial number".

My problem is to combine the self Join with the "general" join of my tables.

I'm using an Access Databdase at the moment.

Comment: Please include your table structures and output (along with sample data) as part of the question, not as a link to an image. The question/answers will be useless to other people in the future if it contains dead links to pertinent information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, please include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you show us what you have?

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/180c4/2) of the tables if anyone wants to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the output you're aiming for with the sample data:

```
with x as (
 select
 row_number() over (partition by t1.Serial order by t1.Serial) as [RN],
 t1.Serial,
 case when t3.Sub_Test_Name = 'AAA' then t3.Value end as [AAA],
 case when t3.Sub_Test_Name = 'BBB' then t3.Value end as [BBB],
 case when t3.Sub_Test_Name = 'CCC' then t3.Value end as [CCC],
 case when t3.Sub_Test_Name = 'DDD' then t3.Value end as [DDD]

 from Table_1 t1
 inner join Table_2 t2 on t2.Table_1_Id = t1.Id
 inner join Table_3 t3 on t3.Table_2_Id = t2.Id
)

select
x.Serial,
AAA.AAA,
BBB.BBB,
CCC.CCC,
DDD.DDD

from x
left outer join x AAA on AAA.Serial = x.Serial and AAA.RN = x.rn + 0
left outer join x BBB on BBB.Serial = x.Serial and BBB.RN = x.rn + 1
left outer join x CCC on CCC.Serial = x.Serial and CCC.RN = x.rn + 2
left outer join x DDD on DDD.Serial = x.Serial and DDD.RN = x.rn + 3

where x.rn = 1
```

This uses self joins as you mentioned (where you see `x` being left joined to itself multiple times in the final select statement).

I've deliberately added extra columns `CCC` and `DDD` so it is easier to see how you would build this out for a larger data set, incrementing the row_number offset for each join.

I've tested this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/180c4/7) and you're welcome to play around with it. If you need to apply additional filters, your `where` clause should be placed inside the CTE.

Note, you're effectively pivoting the data with this sort of query (except we're not aggregating anything, so we can't use the built in `PIVOT` option). The downside of both this method and real pivots is that you have to manually specify **every** column header with its own `CASE` statement in the CTE, and a left join in the final select statement. This can get unwieldy in medium - large data sets, so it best suited in cases where you will have a small number of known column headers in your results.